# connection.setAutoCommit(false) throws error that it's in AutoCommit mode

Tags: c++, mysql

My connection code is given below, which is basically the same as given in their examples. This code was working earlier, but I updated the mysql c++ connector library to 1.1.7 recently and this exception started showing up

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
try {
    conn = driver->connect(dbHost, dbUser, dbPass);
} catch ( ... ) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to connect to database! (Check credentials)");
}

//prints out "Is autocommit - 1"
std::cout<<"Is autocommit - "<<conn->getAutoCommit()<<std::endl; 

conn->setAutoCommit(false); // <- this throws the exception
if ( conn->getAutoCommit() ) throw "Failed to disable auto commit mode!";

conn->setSchema(dbName);
```

The exception type: `N3sql24InvalidArgumentExceptionE`
exception.what(): `The connection is in autoCommit mode`

Comment: Yes, it might be a duplicate, but the other thread is dead and unsolved.

Comment: It's still not supposed to be done like this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260718/duplicates-of-old-cobwebbed-questions

Comment: Is this your driver? https://github.com/anhstudios/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/master/driver/mysql_connection.cpp I don't see any reason for this exception, but you could build the driver from source and debug it to see what goes on in there

Comment: @CherryDT Sadly, that's the old version, I already have that one installed, but it doesn't support prepared statements with multiple result sets (it throws a NotImplementedException). I built the source from their official site (Connector/C++ 1.1.7 - Source code)  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
I'll have to work in autocommit mode it seems, unfortunately